# CakePHP drop down, selected item redirect to view for item

Tags: cakephp, redirect, drop-down-menu

I would like to have the drop down list drugs, redirect to the view for the specific drug chosen. So say they click the drug "Acetamenophen" I want it to send them to the view for that drug. Can I do that without adding a submit button?

Code I have for the drop down:

```
<?php
echo $form->input('Drug.generic', array('type' => 'select', 'label' => 'Quick Select:',
  'empty' => 'Select', 'options' => $alldrugs)
);
?>
```

Index controller action(View the drop down is on)

```
  function index() {
    $this->set('drugs', $this->Drug->find('all'));
    $this->set('alldrugs', $this->Drug->find('list', array('fields' => array('id','generic'), 'order' => 'Drug.generic', 'recursive' => -1,)));
  }
```

Comment: Look into using the [JsHelper::event](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper::event) function to attach a handler for the "change" event.

Comment: you can use jQuey to do this easily without JS helper.

Comment: @thecodeparadox Could you be a bit more specific before I try the JsHelper?

Comment: do u want to use JS helper, of jQuery? jQuery is more easier that Js Helper I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store you root url in a js variable in `default.ctp` like following:

put this code within default.ctp `<head></head>` section.

```
<script>
  var _ROOT = "<?php echo $this->Html->url('/', true); ?>";
</script>
```

And within the `<head>` tag append this line before `</head>` end:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery', 'drug_list')); ?>
```

Then use the `_ROOT` like following:

```
window.location = _ROOT + 'drugs/view/' + val;
```

Place jquery library and make a `YOURNAME.js` file in `app/webroot/js` folder and place following code with `YOURNAME.js` file.

**YOURNAME is as you like**

```
$(function() {
   $('#ID_OF_YOUR_SELECT_BOX').change(function() {   // replace the ID_OF_YOUR_SELECT_BOX with the id to your select box given by Cake
       var val = $(this).val();  // val is the drug id
       window.location = _ROOT + 'drugs/view/' + val;
    });
});
```

Comment: So am I putting this into the view directly as it is, or is this going into the controller?

Comment: So it looks like i'll put this in it's own file and call it at the top of the view?

Comment: @Jonathan you can call it at the top also, but good practice is to make separate `js` file and include it in `default.ctp` file or corresponding view file where to use this code

Comment: I created the drug_list.js file, put the variable in default.ctp and have     echo $javascript->link('drug_list'); in the default.ctp head section. But it doesn't redirect, I probably didn't do the library part correctly.

Comment: cakephp 1.3, lol. I didn't implement everything else, just working with what was done before.

Comment: @Jonathan see update. here replace `jquery` with the jquery library file name that you place within the webroot/js

Answer (score 0):

i'd put the select inside a form without the submit button, and add a `onclick` to the select (you don't actually need a whole framework for it):

```
<?php
echo $form->input('Drug.generic', array('type' => 'select', 'label' => 'Quick Select:',
  'empty' => 'Select', 'options' => $alldrugs, 'onchange'=>'this.form.submit();')
);
?>
```

of course in the controller you'd have to check the `this->data` and redirect the user to the correct page depending on the select, or if you dont want to redirect the user, just change the condition on the find().

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

With a mix of jQuery and PHP, you can redirect directly to the action you want:

```
<?php
echo $form->input('Drug.generic', array('type' => 'select', 'label' => 'Quick Select:',
  'empty' => 'Select', 'options' => $alldrugs, 'id' => 'drug_select')
);
?>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#drug_select").change(function(){
        var drug_id = $(this).val();
        if(drug_id.length > 0)
        {
            window.location = "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'drugs', 'action' => 'view'), true) ?>/" + drug_id;
        }
    });

});
```